# ReactJS: Handle Role for User

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jhipster

I have a page that I use to check the user authorization

```
const Routes = auth => {
  return (
    <div className="view-routes">
//...
    <PrivateRoute
          path="/"
          component={Entities}
          hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER, AUTHORITIES.ADMIN]}
        />
    // so in this case, the hasAnyAuthorities check if the user has one of this role and return true so I will see the component Entities for this user.
)}
```

Now I need to add another user's role. So I have add :

```
const Routes = auth => {
  return (
    <div className="view-routes">
//...
 <PrivateRoute
          path="/"
          component={Menu2}
          hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER_APP]}
        />
    <PrivateRoute
          path="/"
          component={Entities}
          hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER, AUTHORITIES.ADMIN]}
        />
)}
```

In this way only the first component (menu2) is always shown. So if I enter with role "USER_APP" I can see the fields in component Menu2. But if I login with role: "ADMIN" I can't see fields inside Entities, as if only the first of the two PrivateRoute were controlled.

*What would to obtain:*

> If I enter with role: USER_APP I'll see the fields in component Menu2.

> If I ente with role ADMIN I'll see the fields in the component Entities.

How can I do?

Comment: Both routes have the same path, so it probably always uses the first.

Comment: Yes it is. So I should use different path?

Comment: Yes, I think you should use a different path, e.g. `/admin`, or `/entities` or whaterver makes most sense in your app.